# How to have the same hash from a folder on windows and linux?

Tags: linux, 7-zip

I was using 7zip to compute the hash of a folder (with subfolders), which it can do with two options, with or without including the file names.

However, on the linux version of 7zip, the hash feature is not implemented. I tried different [methods](https://superuser.com/questions/458326/sha1sum-for-a-directory-of-directories) to duplicate the result, but none of these methods would give the same result on linux and windows.

Examples of results :

"`7za.exe h -scrcsha1 myfolder`" on windows gives :

```
SHA1   for data:              D54D3168B16BFEE600C3A77E848A2A1C1DBCBC59
SHA1   for data and names:    BCE55085200581AD1774CC25AE065DE7DE60077D
```

, whereas on linux I have :

```
find . -type f -exec sha1sum "$PWD"/{} \; | sha1sum
ee44137f2462bdfea87ec824dab514f288ae3e6c  -
```

or

```
find . -type f | xargs sha1sum | sha1sum
8f971311a28bcdee36fab0ce87a892564622db40  -
```

So I can't use the result from one platform on another.

(I did verify that the result for a single file is the same for both platforms.)

Comment: Is making a hash of each file, and then hashing this an option?

Comment: What didn't work about the accepted answer you linked to? `find . -type f -exec sha1sum "$PWD"/{} \; | sha1sum` - can you tell us the problems?

Answer (score 3):

Simply running the following command won't necessarily work:

```
find . -type f | xargs sha512sum | sha512sum
```

The issue you may face is that the order of files reported by `find` is different from system-to-system or even from directory copy to copy.

Instead, try running the following:

```
find . -type f | sort | xargs sha512sum | sha512sum
```

Feel free to swap `sha512sum` for another - e.g: `md5sum` / `sha1sum` / `sha256sum` depending on your requirements.

Note that this may get slow for large directory trees, in which case you may prefer a more complex script to traverse the hierarchy.

---

Example:

```
$ find . -type f | xargs sha512sum | sha512sum
097e56f6b751c1da15ce5b9dce853ffcc89e06e9cbe10a8dc0894dedb834d40dc4228c65e48bd53f136dd6a7700b0ab07e8e12e7100956db00b0d1b9ef0b9956  -
```

This includes file names and content in the final hash, but does not include metadata - modification times, permissions, etc...

---

Note that you can use these utilities on Windows by using "[*Windows Subsystem for Linux*](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/wsl/about)". I've just installed it, which was a painless experience, and which also made me realise the issue with `find`'s reported ordering.

Also watch out for how symbolic links are handled in your tree on Linux vs. Windows.

Comment: Thanks, but how can I come to the same hash value on windows ?

Comment: Can you edit your question with the output of `find . -type f | xargs sha512sum` from each system - try a small example directory. I wonder if the backwards slashes are causing issues... Or if your directories are actually different.

Comment: Oh... I've just re-read your question... do you have ["_Windows Subsystem for Linux_"](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/wsl/about) setup? You should be able to run the same command on both systems.

Comment: I don't have this installed, but it seems a bit overkill for my case, I'm looking for a stand alone exe or similar. (I ultimately want to use the solution from nodejs exec command line on any computer after just an nsis install of my application+dependancies)

Comment: Well if you're using NodeJS, then this is a different question... You're not looking for a set of utilities to achieve a goal, you're interested in how to implement your required features.

Comment: Hmmm, just by stating it I realized that I was so focused on command line due to my previous use of 7z that I did not think of looking for a native nodejs tool, and there is actually one : https://www.npmjs.com/package/folder-hash... I'll try that and maybe post it as an answer if it delivers the same result on both plateforms.

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately,it seems that it's impossible to reproduce the hash of a folder generated by 7-zip.

This is becasuse 7z uses the FindNextFileW() function to enumerate the directories (7z-1900src/CPP/Windows/FileFind.cpp, line 198).

The order of the function's return value is not guaranteed and can be file system dependent (According to https://docs.microsoft.com/zh-cn/windows/win32/api/fileapi/nf-fileapi-findnextfilew).

So if you want to impliment a platform independent directory hashing function, you should use an unified sorting function.

Answer (score 1):

Since Linux cannot duplicate the 7zip checksum and I do not have nodeJS, I installed "Windows Subsystem for Linux" to verify a folder copy from a Windows computer to a Synology NAS. Installing WSL was quite painless, just follow [the docs](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/wsl/about).

For a command which actually generated the same hash on both Windows and Linux, I primarily referred to [How can I calculate an MD5 checksum of a directory?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7838345/6047827), which explains how to sort results consistently between Windows and Linux and also how NOT to ignore empty directories. Sorting consistently is accomplished with `LC_ALL=C`:

```
find . -type f -print0 | LC_ALL=C sort -z | xargs -r0  sha512sum | sha512sum
```

But that doesn't handle empty directories, so here is a more complete command copied from the other answer. It does not use `-print0` to reduce complexity, but Windows doesn't permit newlines and such special characters in file/folder names anyway so no big deal.

```
dir=<mydir>; (find "$dir" -type f -exec md5sum {} +; find "$dir" -type d) | LC_ALL=C sort | md5sum
```

Lastly, the Synology creates extra files/folders for indexing, so I also had to ignore the index files with `-not -path`. This was my final command which generated the same checksum in WSL for my Windows folder and in Synology SSH for the copied folder:

```
dir=.; (find "$dir" -type f -not -path '*@eaDir*' -exec sha512sum {} +; find "$dir" -type d -not -path '*@eaDir*') | LC_ALL=C sort | sha512sum
```